# Proving differentiability of |x| at non-zero point

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

To prove |x| is not differentiable at $0$, I'd convert to a piecewise function first.

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x, & x\ge 0  \\
-x, & {x<0}
\end{cases}$

Approaching from the left of $0$, x is negative so $f(x) = -x$ and from the right, it's $f(x) = x$

Using $$f'(x)=\lim_{x \to h} \frac{f(x)-f(h)}{x-h}$$ definition, i'd show the left and right limits were different to prove the limit does not exist.

My question is, how would I show this is differentiable at, say, x=5? The values of x approaching 5 from the left would transition from negative to positive (so be both less than and greater than 0), so which of the two functions would apply?

Comment: Actually write down the difference quotient for $x=5$ and a small value of $h$ and see what you get. Then decide whether you need to worry about approaching from the left or the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the definition of your limit is wrong. It should be that $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to x} \frac{f(x)-f(h)}{x-h} $$ We should let the dummy variable $h$ to approach the input value $x$, but not the other way round.

Back to your question, you can always think of computing limit is to find out what happens when things are ***arbitrarily close*** to (not just close or verrry close), but never at the point you are taking to. For example, to check if $|x|$ is differentiable at $x=5$, you may come across the limit 
$$f'(5)=\lim_{h\to 5} \frac{f(5)-f(h)}{5-h} $$ Since here you are taking $h\to5$, you just have to think of what will happen when $h$ is arbitrarily close to $5$. In that case, probably you won't say that $0$ is close to $5$ since **we can always insert other numbers between $0$ and $5$**, and what are close to $5$ should be those positive numbers. Hence, taking $f(h)=h$ serves you well to compute the limit. After that, you will then see $$f'(5)=\lim_{h\to 5} \frac{5-h}{5-h}=\lim_{h\to5}1=1$$Hence, the limit exists and $f$ is differentiable at $x=5$.

In fact, to demonstrate the notion of ***arbitrary closeness***, we can also apply the same reasoning to show that $f'(0.1)=f'(0.01)=f'(0.001)=1$, that is, $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x)=1$ whenever $x>0$.

To conclude, what I said about computing limit is far too intuitive: what is really meant by *arbitrarily close* to certain points? A bad news is that probably at your stage, you would not be able to fully understand the real gist of the limit concept to describe the concept of nearness and convergence with its rigorous definition. A good news is that the above notion of limit to consider things *arbitrarily close* to the limiting point by your intuition should serve you well computing the limit problems you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>0$, $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|x|-|x|+h}{h} = 1$.

For $x<0$, $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|x|-|x|-h}{h} = -1$.

Comment: Please note that the OP did not ask about differentiability at $x=0$ (which he knew how to deal with) but at $x=5$.

Comment: Why is $|x+h|=|x|+h$ in your first expression?  Cannot $h$ be negative here?

Comment: It can be negative. Remember that approaching 0 from either side  is important. This is not the case at $x=0$.

Comment: Actually, for $x>0$, you can consider $|h|<\frac{x}{2}$ to keep $x+h>0$.  Nevertheless, the limit as $h \rightarrow 0$ means approaching from the left and right (positive and negative h's).  A similar statement applies when $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same definition to prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x\ne0$:

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}x, & x\ge 0  \\
-x, & {x<0}
\end{cases}$

For $x>0, \quad f(x)=x, \quad f'(x)=1$.

For $x<0, \quad f(x)=-x, \quad f'(x)=-1$.

Comment: Corrected typo.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For any non-zero point, either it is $>0$ or $<0$. So we have that:

$f(x) = x\ \text{or} -x$ depending on where the point lies.

(i) Suppose $x_0 > 0$, then
$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^{+}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \frac{x-x_0}{x-x_0} = 1,\ $ and $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^{-}} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \frac{x-x_0}{x-x_0} = 1$ 
Here note that if $x_0 > 0,$ then $x \to x_0^{+} \Rightarrow x-x_0 > 0$ and $x \to x_0^{-} \Rightarrow x-x_0 < 0$. But the numerator and denominator have same sign therefore we get one.

The other case you can do I guess.